# What is the correct/idiomatic way of handling possible null values from a database query?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, pgx

I'm handling a many-to-many relationship in Go. For this, I'm using the [`pgx`](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) PostgreSQL driver.

For the sake of keeping this question as simple as possible, let's assume a simple blog post that can have some tags:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    tagName varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_tag (
    post_id bigint REFERENCES post (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    tag_id bigint REFERENCES tag (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT post_tag_pkey PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id)
);
```

To retrieve posts and their tags, I use something like the following query (in a view for easy querying in Go):

```sql
SELECT p.id as post_id, p.title, p.description, t.id as tag_id, t.tagName as tag_name
    FROM post p 
    LEFT JOIN post_tag pt
    ON p.id = pt.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tag t 
    ON t.id = pt.tag_id;
```

This query will likely return some rows where `tag_id` and `tag_name` are null. The way I'm currently handling this, is the following (error handling removed for sake of simplicity):

```golang
func ReadPosts() ([]*model.Post, error) {
    var posts []*model.Post
    var postWithTags = make(map[uint64]*model.Post)

    statement := `SELECT *
                    FROM post_with_tag` // pgsql view with joins to get tags

    rows, _ := db.Query(
        context.Background(),
        statement,
    )

    for rows.Next() {
        var (
            post     model.Post
            tag      model.Tag
            tagID    pgtype.Numeric
            tagName  pgtype.Varchar
            tagValid bool
        )

        _ = rows.Scan(
            &post.ID,
            &post.Title,
            &post.Description,
            &tagID,
            &tagName,
        )

        if tagID.Status == pgtype.Present {
            tag.ID = tagID.Int.Uint64()
            tag.Name = tagName.String
            tagValid = true
        } else {
            tagValid = false
        }

        if _, ok := postWithTags[post.ID]; ok {
            if tagValid {
                postWithTags[post.ID].Tags = append(postWithTags[post.ID].Tags, &tag)
            }
        } else {
            post.Tags = []*model.Tag{}

            if tagValid {
                post.Tags = []*model.Tag{
                    &tag,
                }
            }

            postWithTags[post.ID] = &post
        }
    }

    for _, v := range postWithTags {
        posts = append(posts, v)
    }

    return posts, nil
}
```

As you can see, I'm using [`pgtype`](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype) to handle the potential null values. I should mention that **this solution works**. However, I have two issues:

1. This solution seems quite clunky and messy; it's complex to read (at least to me). **Is there a better, more idiomatic Go way of doing this?**
2. When calling `tagID.Int.Uint64()` I always get returned `0` as the tag ID, which is not correct. **Is there something I'm doing wrong here?** (I'm using `pgtype.Numeric` because the tag ID in the database is a pgsql `bigint`).

Comment: 1) "better, more idiomatic" is opinion-based; how specifically do you want to improve it? 2) postgres `bigint` is 8 bytes, i.e. 64 bits, i.e. you can just use `int64`.

Comment: Use [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in the query? This assumes there is some suitable placeholder value you can use in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a table view and you don't need to filter by `NULL` (e.g. `WHERE col IS [NOT] NULL`) then you may want to just use `COALESCE` in the view, that way you can save yourself some headache at the Go end. If you're dealing directly with tables, you can still use `COALESCE` in your SQL `statement` string that you've constructed in Go, however if you choose to do that you will not be able to use it together with `SELECT *`, instead you will have to list the columns explicitly.

If you don't like the `COALESCE` approach you can implement your own `sql.Scanner` that, instead of having a value field, would have a pointer field which then allows you to set your model fields by indirection on the same line as the one on which you're scanning the columns.

```
_ = rows.Scan(
    &post.ID,
    &post.Title,
    &post.Description,
    MyNullNumeric{&tag.ID},
    MyNullString{&tag.Name},
)
```

And the `MyNullXxx` could look like this:

```
type MyNullString struct {
    Ptr *string
}

func (ns MyNullString) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        *ns.Ptr = v
    case []byte:
        *ns.Ptr = string(v)
    case nil:
        // nothing
    default:
        // maybe nothing or error, up to you
    }
    return nil
}
```